# React JS Scripts on package.json cannot yarn multiple script

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I added on scripts on `package.json`:

1. `yarn build`
2. `yarn serve`
3. `yarn start` (to run `yarn build` and `yarn serve`)

But the problem is when I run `yarn start`, the terminal cannot run `yarn serve` but `yarn build` is successfully running:

[image]

When I run them separately, both are working:

[image]

```json
 {
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
    "lite-server": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --out-dir public -w",
    "serve": "lite-server --baseDir public",
    "start": "yarn build & yarn serve"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a second "&" in `yarn build && yarn serve`

Comment: It's not working